# Get or download Shelf Code in Team Foundation Server (TFS)

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012

I am fairly new to TFS, like Mel from this post:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/142977/27650

I had a project on another PC, but I have been issued another PC.

Yes, I could go to management, and bug them with all of the various steps involved with finding and then getting my shelf project that I was working on last week, but I would rather find the information on my own.

I found MSDN's article on [Shelve and Unshelve Pending Changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181404.aspx), but it did not cover how to get my shelf item. Perhaps there is a special term that I am unfamiliar with.

Likewise, I read over the article [What's New in Visual Studio TFS 2012](http://devproconnections.com/visual-studio-2012/whats-new-visual-studio-tfs-2012), since we are using VS2012. It appears to go over the changes that have occurred since the newest release.

### How do I find my shelf items, so that I can continue working on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is answered under "Unshelving" on the page you referred to (Shelve and Unshelve Pending Changes). You click on unshelve and first step you do is finding your sehlveset. However please remember it works only if you shelved your changes before you lost your PC.

Comment: Then something isn't working. I have about 20 different shelf updates, but whenever I try to *unshelf* my latest save, all it pulls down is the one file that I updated with that shelf action instead of getting me the snapshot of the project at that point in time.

Comment: This is how shelveset works. Its a set of  pending changes that you can restore, not a workspace snapshot. This is how the linked page describes it.

Comment: In your case, you can do Get specific version in source control explorer and download files from the time you built your old pc. Then unshelve your change

Comment: How would I find what version the software was at when I started my project? The software has been updated 3 or 4 times since I started my version. After downloading the correct version, would I need to download each shelf item in the order that I added them?

Comment: What do you mean by "started your version"? Do you mean since you downloaded files to your workspace? Are those new updates so dramatic that you cannot integrate your unshelved files with latest changes? You will need to do it eventually. You need to unshelve only the latest shelveset.

Comment: I started by getting the latest version from TFS, then I got my latest shelf. That latest shelf was only me adding a new signature for one of our database access methods. That shelf will download that, but not the months of updates I have done on the whole application.

Comment: I just deleted the TFS folder contents, and started a new download using a version from 01 February. Once that is complete, I will try unshelving my items, oldest first, in the hope that it will work. Man, I really wished I had known TFS was going to do that. I could have easily copied my handful of files to a flash drive and been done hours ago.

Comment: What do other shelvesets contain? I dont know how you created them so not sure why this particular one does not contain all your changes

Comment: Good luck! I would start unshelving starting with the newest. Not sure if you can unshelve over already existing change

Comment: I made several shelf changes. I like to do it daily, so that my work stays backed up. My project started with a lot of refactoring, then renaming variables from `textbox12` to `txtPartNumber`, renaming methods from `button1_Click` to `btnAddData_Click`, etc. Lots and lots of stuff I changed.

Comment: Keep in mind: Shelvesets are intended for **short term**, context-free suspension of work-in-progress, not as an alternative to branches or regularly committing changes.

Answer (score 0):

I got this resolved, but I did not like the way I found to do it.

In Team Explorer, I opened my last successful shelf item, did a **Right-Click** and selected **View Shelfset Details**:

[image: last shelf item]

From there, I went to **each file** listed in the **Changes to Unshelf** list.

I selected **Open** for that file, and then physically copied the text from that file to the corresponding file on my PC.

Again, I did this for each file that had changed in my **Shelfset Details**.

[image: view details]

For whatever reason, *Team Foundation Server* does not pull that data back into my project whenever I select the *"Unshelve Changes"* option.